# N-Genius Payment Gateway Integration in Angular - Seeking Guidance

Tags: angular, integration, payment-gateway

Description:

I have a basic understanding of the N-Genius payment gateway API calls, but I'm struggling with the integration process into my Angular application. I would appreciate guidance on how to structure the integration and where to place the API calls within my Angular project.

Specific Questions:

1.How do I initiate the N-Genius payment gateway integration in an Angular component?

2.Where should I handle the API calls within my Angular application (e.g., in a service, component, or other)?

3.How do i redirect to the payment gateway portal when i get the redirect url from payment gateway api response?

4.Are there any specific considerations or best practices for integrating N-Genius into an Angular application?

Environment Details:

I am using Angular version 16.2.9 and Node version 16.16.0 for my project.